Select top ranking product accross categories excluding products selected before
I want to get top ranked products across passed categories id list. But I want to get only unique products for every category excluding top products found before.
Following tables is simplified example.
product_category
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
|     1      |       1     |
|     2      |       1     |
|     3      |       1     |
|     4      |       1     |
|     1      |       2     |
|     2      |       2     |
|     3      |       2     |
|     4      |       2     |
+------------+-------------+

products
+------------+-------------+
| product_id |     hits    |
+------------+-------------+
|     1      |      123    |
|     2      |      333    |
|     3      |      444    |
|     4      |      555    |
+------------+-------------+

For example i want to get top ranked products for categories [1,2]
+-------------+-------------+
| category_id |  product_id |
+-------------+-------------+
|     1       |      4      |
|     2       |      3      | <-- because product_id = 4 is used before
+-------------+-------------+

So main goal is to get top ranked unique products across passed categories list. Now we have approach to query every category consequentially excluding top products found before. But this way produces a lot of database requests.
Is there any way to perform this operation with a single query?

This does not have solution since you haven't specified an order. In your wanted result the product_ids could be switched just as well. When the categories include the same top products, what determines which of the categories gets the product with the most hits, and which the second most hits, etc.?  Do you want the lowest category_id to have the product with the most hits or ... ? And what have you tried yourself? Please give us your attempt, and the (Wrong) results.

@Roemer We can order it by category ids, it doesnt matter which category get first top ranked product. I want to get list of non-dupicated products for passed categories ordered by hits. Excluding my attempts, I've spent hours with gpt with no success - it gives me only top products at the end :(

The trouble I am having is to deal with products that have the same number of hits, but we're getting there... patience...

After searching long and hard I came to this:
WITH productPlusCategory AS (
    SELECT 
        pc.product_id,
        pc.category_id,
        p.hits,
        CAST(hits AS DECIMAL(18,9)) + p.product_id / 1000000000 AS unique_hits
    FROM 
        product_category pc
    JOIN 
        products p USING (product_id)
),
MaxUniqueHits AS (
    SELECT 
        category_id, 
        MAX(unique_hits) AS max_unique_hits
    FROM 
        productPlusCategory
    GROUP BY 
        category_id
)

SELECT 
    ppc.product_id,
    ppc.category_id,
    ppc.hits
FROM 
    productPlusCategory ppc
JOIN 
    MaxUniqueHits muh
    ON ppc.category_id = muh.category_id
    AND ppc.unique_hits = muh.max_unique_hits
WHERE 
    ppc.product_id NOT IN (
        SELECT product_id 
        FROM 
            productPlusCategory ppc2 
        JOIN 
            MaxUniqueHits muh2
            ON ppc2.category_id = muh2.category_id
            AND ppc2.unique_hits = muh2.max_unique_hits
        WHERE ppc2.category_id < ppc.category_id
    )
ORDER BY ppc.category_id;

Sandbox: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/42upmvvp2
One of my main problems was to identify products uniquely when they have the same number of hits. For this I added a calculated column unique_hits, adding the primary key behind the decimal point. (Can give unexpected results if hits is not integer or primary keys have more than 9 digits. So should work in most use cases.) This way there is technically always one product with maximum hits and not more.
By using WITH you can prevent a lot of repetition because otherwise it gets really out of hand. I have a WITH that selects the maximum hits per category and one that joins products with their categories.
Notice that I basically have the same query nested, twice. The outer one calculates the maximums. The WHERE ppc.product_id NOT IN (...) avoids the repetition. The ... contains almost the same query as the main query, thus reproducing all the maxima for all categories with a category_id smaller than the current one via WHERE ppc2.category_id < ppc.category_id, so with NOT IN(...) it does not select it if it already "has been" in a "earlier" category (smaller category_id). (Using quotes because that's a very human interpretation and not how it technically works.)
This should work (please test). But it is not efficient. It will join the same tables four times! It will help if you have good indices. Programming the deduplication in another language would probably be the better option if your tables are large.
EDIT To practice my WITHs I added another version that makes it even clearer what is happening. What I explained above you can see much clearer now in the query itself. It will not be more efficient, might be less efficient.
WITH productPlusCategory AS (
    SELECT 
        pc.product_id,
        pc.category_id,
        p.hits,
        CAST(hits AS DECIMAL(18,9)) + p.product_id / 1000000000 AS unique_hits
    FROM 
        product_category pc
    JOIN 
        products p USING (product_id)
),
MaxUniqueHits AS (
    SELECT 
        category_id, 
        MAX(unique_hits) AS max_unique_hits
    FROM 
        productPlusCategory
    GROUP BY 
        category_id
),
FindMaximums AS (
    SELECT 
        ppc.product_id,
        ppc.category_id,
        ppc.hits
    FROM 
        productPlusCategory ppc
    JOIN 
        MaxUniqueHits muh
        ON ppc.category_id = muh.category_id
        AND ppc.unique_hits = muh.max_unique_hits
)

SELECT * FROM FindMaximums fm
WHERE 
    product_id NOT IN (
        SELECT product_id FROM FindMaximums fm2
        WHERE fm2.category_id < fm.category_id
    )
ORDER BY category_id;


Thank you for an attempt. Unfortunately it returns only one row.

I'm sorry, but you must have made a mistake somewhere in your data or your copying. It works. Look here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/42upmvvp2

Mind you my testdata was a bit different to yours,  to test with two products with the same nr of hits. You can alter the data for more testing in the sandbox if you want.
